# Is it possible to see the running timer on the lock screen in iOS 14?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-lock, clock

In iOS 13, a running timer was shown on the lock screen, so picking up your iPhone was enough to quickly see the remaining time without needing to unlock it:

[image]

In iOS 14.0.1 this feature is gone, so in order to see the remaining time on a timer you need to unlock your iPhone, find the Clock app, and switch to the Timers tab.

Is it possible to see the remaining time on the lock screen in iOS 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [Force Restart your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios), the timer will magically appear on the Lock Screen. I hadn't noticed this, but verified the problem after applying this solution.

Answer found at [Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251883752).

Comment: That's totally bizarre, but it works. Many thanks

Comment: Even stranger, the timer reverted to the default behaviour after the latest minor iOS upgrade. I had to force restart again to restore the time on the lock screen

Comment: I'll have to check this out myself. Thanks for the update! If this is true, perhaps we should [provide feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) about the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just submitted a bug report

Comment: Odd. It didn't happen to my freshly-updated iPhone 8 (iOS 14.2.)